# What is this Pirates of the Caribbean-ish maritime orchestral music?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

Could somebody recognize this piece of orchestral music.

https://youtu.be/SOW-xJpm0Rs?t=18s

It sounds very similar to the soundtrack of popular "Pirates of the Caribbean" movie series, but melody is not the same. I went through those soundtrack compilations briefly, but could not catch this particular piece.

Audio recognition software (Shazam, Google Assistant, AudioTag) were of no help.

I would like to know the name of the track if it is indeed from the movies, or a direction where to look, if it is not.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm almost sure it is a [soundalike](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4144/a-piece-of-music-that-is-almost-identical-to-another-is-called) from a [music library](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/4775/3260), but I have no proof of this...

Comment: you could post questions under the video on youtube.....but I agree with @Bebs, there is a lot of music out there from music libraries, and unless there is something unusual or distinctive about the music or the context, it is very very hard to track down the piece.

Comment: @Angst I didn't feel like youtube comment would've helped in this case, since the video has very low view count and because of reasons you pointed out above (did anything ever got resolved in YT comments anyway). Besides, pori already found the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zapotec by Jeffrey Fayman, Owain Llwyd, Yoav Goren](http://www.deezer.com/en/track/5140701)

But I could not find "no choir" version.